# Only show DataTable Edit/Delete Column if User is in a specific role

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, datatables

I am still relatively new to MVC and JS so I might be trying to do this the wrong way.

I'm using DataTables in my MVC Project to display a list of Products from the Database.
On the end column, I have an Edit and Delete button which should only be visible for Users in the Admin Role. If they are not in the Admin Role then it should still load the table and just hide that column.

**ProductDTController:**

```
public class ProductDTController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

        public ProductDTController(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            List<Product> productList = new List<Product>();
            return View(productList);
        }

        #region API CALLS
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetAll()
        {
            List<Product> productList = _db.Products.ToList();
            return Json(new { data = productList });
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model List<Product>

<div class="card shadow border-0 my-4">
    <div class="card-header bg-secondary bg-gradient m-lg-0 pt-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 text-center">
                <h2 class="text-white py-2">Product List</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body p-4">
        <div class="row pb-3">
            <div class="col-6">
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 text-end">
                <a asp-controller="Product" asp-action="Upsert" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <i class="bi bi-plus-circle"></i>
                    Create New Product
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <table id="tblData" class="table table-bordered table-striped" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Brand</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/js/product.js"></script>
}
```

**product.js**

```
var dataTable;

$(document).ready(function () {
    loadDataTable();
});

function loadDataTable() {
    dataTable = $('#tblData').DataTable({
        ajax: { url: '/ProductDT/GetAll' },
        columns: [
            { data: 'productId', "width": "25%" },
            { data: 'productName', "width": "25%" },
            { data: 'productBrand', "width": "15%" },
            { data: 'productDescription', "width": "10%" },
            {
                data: 'id',
                "render": function (data) {
                    return `<div class="w-75 btn-group" role="group">
                    <a href="ProductDT/Edit?id=${data}" class="btn btn-primary mx-2"><i class="bi bi-pencil-square"></i> Edit</a>
                    <a onClick=Delete('ProductDT/Delete?id=${data}') class="btn btn-danger mx-2"><i class="bi bi-trash-fill"></i> Delete</a>
                    </div>`
                },
                "width": "25%"
            }
        ]
    });
}
```

Within the Index.cshtml - I have tried doing:

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
                    {
                        <th>Action</th>
                    } else
                    {
                        <th hidden>Action</th>
                    }
```

This will only stop the column header from appearing, but still put the Edit and Delete Buttons in the column.

I have tried doing some Razor Syntax within the product.js, but it doesn't get recognized.

The Users role will come from the AspNetUsers table in the database.

Answer (score 0):

In your JavaScript have a boolean variable that says whether this user is an Admin

```js
const isAdmin = $('#isAdmin').val();
```

Then in your DataTable columns definition set the [visible](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.visible) property for the column  you want to hide

```js
{
    data: 'id',
    render: function (data) {
        return `<div class="w-75 btn-group" role="group">
        <a href="ProductDT/Edit?id=${data}" class="btn btn-primary mx-2"><i class="bi bi-pencil-square"></i> Edit</a>
        <a onClick=Delete('ProductDT/Delete?id=${data}') class="btn btn-danger mx-2"><i class="bi bi-trash-fill"></i> Delete</a>
        </div>`
    },
    width: "25%",
    visible: isAdmin
}
```

Please be aware that any user can view the JavaScript for the page and modify this value, so you *must* also check on the server whether the user has the correct permission.